# unable to take the datepicker value in the query

Tags: vba, ms-access, datepicker

My access 2013 database kept showing me an MSCAL.OCX error. Searching on web gave me an idea to use the date picker.
I tried to put two date pickers(start date and end date) and use these values in my query. This was my query before:

```
 SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
    [program form] 
WHERE 
    [program form].[Program date]>=[Beginning Date] 
    And 
    [program form].[Program date])<=[Ending Date];
```

This is my query after using the date picker values:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [program form] 
WHERE
    [program form].[Program date] >=[start_date_picker] 
    And
    [program form].[Program date] <=[end_date_picker];
```

Now it gives me a form or report event error stating " A macro specified as the OnOpen, OnLoad, OnClose, OnRetreat, OnPage, or OnPrint property setting contains an invalid action for the property. When you click OK, an action Failed dialog box will display the name of the macro that failed and its arguments

this problem started after i upgraded to access 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only have changed the parameter request name. Nothing much other than that. In my opinion the error is because of Missing or broken reference. **MSCAL.OCX** was used in older versions of Access where Date Controls were not available. Recent versions do not need this reference. See if you can rectify your error using this : http://www.access-diva.com/d5.html

Comment: the mscal error seems to be gone but now the query would not fetch recent additions to the database.

Comment: @user2428261, what exactly do you mean by it would not fetch recent additions?